# Change default database in cakephp controller

Tags: php, database, cakephp

Using CakePHP version : 2.3.1

I have a default database that I use for authorisation, and based on that, different databases for different clients (database names have client names in it).

I have many models with various relationships between them. I want to retrieve them using one call (which recursively retrieves all associated model data).

Scenario:

Databases

```
default :
clients 
[id, password, name]
[1, 'qwertycolemak', 'amazon']
[2, '5t4ck0verfl0w', 'ebay']
```

Non-default databases(next 2)

```
client_amazon
students[student_id, student_name]
course_students [student_id, course_id]
courses [course_id, course_name]

client_ebay
(same as client_amazon)
```

Now, suppose I get request for [id:2, password:'5t4ck0verfl0w']
I check default database (*clients*), check password, retrieve name, in this case **ebay**

Now , the database I want to access is **'client_ebay'**

I have different configs in database.php corresponding to each client.
I tried changing datasource by using

```
$this->student->setDatasource('client_ebay')
$this->course->setDatasource('client_ebay')
$this->course_student->setDatasource('client_ebay')
```

This works for individual CRUD calls to models(non-recursive).

But when I use a call (with recursion on) like

```
$this->student->findById(5)
```

datasource defaults to 'default', and I get an error :
**Table *students* for model *student* was not found in datasource *default***

How do I change the default datasource for all models(not one by one) dynamically through the controller?

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version! ps, is there a reason why you need to use separate databases?

Comment: when you change your source, is it persistent ? or does it reset back to default after the first query ? i would look into that

Comment: Added cakePHP version

@ndm
I am handling transactions for different clients, so I need to keep them separate

Comment: @AyoAkinyemi
Changing source is definitely persistent for individual models
The problem only occurs when cakePHP tries to recursively retrieve associated data, in terms of database relationships. Then, it automatically switches to default.

Comment: gotcha! how about writing a function in your appModel class that sets the source to one you want, and when you are done with your query, have another function that resets it to default. since all the models will go through the appModel anyways, the function will always make sure any model uses the datasource you set it to.

Comment: @AyoAkinyemi

I'm a newbie at this.
What function would I use in the function that I write in the AppModel?
"setDataSource()" individually for each model, or a single call that changes datasource for all models.
Please elaborate.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: how deep is your association ?

Comment: At its maximum, it is 2 levels deep.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model layer executes all DB operations on the object returned from [`Model::getDataSource()`](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-Model.html#_getDataSource), so overwriting that method in your `AppModel` class and setting the proper datasource in there when necessary might be an option.

Here's an (untested) example, this would set the datasource to whatever is configured in `Model.globalSource` if necessary (and in case a value is set at all). The value could be changed wherever it's possible to call [`Configure::write()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/configuration.html#Configure%3a%3awrite).

```
...

class AppModel extends Model
{
    ...

    public function getDataSource()
    {
        $source = Configure::read('Model.globalSource');
        if($source !== null && $source !== $this->useDbConfig)
        {
            $this->setDataSource($source);
        }

        return parent::getDataSource();
    }

    ...
}
```

In your controller you could then do something like

```
Configure::write('Model.globalSource', 'client_ebay');
$student = $this->Student->findById(5);
```

Comment: Can we use it for useDbConfig instead of setDataSource?

Comment: @Anupal Changing only the `$useDbConfig` property might not be enough as this will leave the schema name and the table prefix unchanged.

Comment: especially when I do App::import

Comment: @ndm Why do you think schema name and table prefix unchanged? If I create new connection like `ConnectionManager::create()` with all basic parameters which I have used in `default` datasource in `database.php`.

Comment: @Parixit Look at the source and check what `setSource()` and `setDataSource()` do. If you'd only change the `useDbConfig` property, then these methods wouldn't be invoked.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried modifying the $useDbConfig attribute of the Model? For example:

```
$this->Student->useDbConfig = 'client_ebay';
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried both methods (useDbConfig and setDatasource) individually and  together.

Answer (score 0):

**Example in controller, Change multi DB for DataSources in CakePHP 2.5.x**

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class DemoController extends AppController {

public $uses = array('AppModel', 'GVA21', 'GVA01', 'GVA14', 'GVA24' );
public function test_dbs(){
    $this->autoRender=false;
    // Load ConnectManager
    App::uses('ConnectionManager', 'Model');
    // DataSource ['default']
    $MDM = $this->GVA14->find('count');
    echo "MDM.GVA14\n<br>";
    debug($MDM);
    // Get DataSource Config DB ['default'] and ['SRL']
    $confDeafult = ConnectionManager::$config->default;
    $confSrl = ConnectionManager::$config->SRL;
    // Change DataSource ['SRL']
    ConnectionManager::drop('default');
    ConnectionManager::create('default',$confSrl);  //<== Is permanet change Find All models Down
    // $this->GVA01->setDataSource('SRL'); //<== Is temp change Find model
    echo "SRL.GVA14\n<br>";
    $SRL = $this->GVA14->find('count');
    debug($SRL);
    $SRL = $this->GVA01->find('count');
    echo "SRL.GVA01\n<br>";
    debug($SRL);
    $SRL = $this->GVA21->find('count');
    echo "SRL.GVA21\n<br>";
    debug($SRL);
    // Change to DataSource ['default']
    debug(ConnectionManager::drop('default'));
    ConnectionManager::create('default',$confDeafult); //<== Is permanet change Find All models Down
    //$this->GVA01->setDataSource('default'); //<== Is temp change Find model
    $MDM = $this->GVA01->find('count');
    echo "MDM.GVA01\n<br>";
    debug($MDM);
    $MDM = $this->GVA21->find('count');
    echo "MDM.GVA21\n<br>";
    debug($MDM);
    ////FIN
    exit('FIN');
}
```